# How to send back validation error to Angular2 app

Tags: angular, validation, wakanda

In a component of my Angular4 app I use the save method of an entity. The validate event is executed before the save process and returns an error object in case of an error.
How do I get the custom error object from the validate event?

Component:

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.workTimeDialogParams.entity.save()).subscribe(
    res => {
        debugger;
    },
    err => {
        debugger;
    }
);
```

server side validate event:

```
model.XXX.events.validate = function(event) {
    var result = {};

    if (checkCondition === false) {
        result.error = 123,
        result.errorMessage = 'The value is to long'
    }

    return result ;
};
```

In the subscribe function I want to get the specific error (for example *123 "The value is to long"*) sent by the validate function of the server and not the general error *500 "Internal server error"*.

Comment: Not use in a validate, just use the Promise in the submit function

Comment: Why use Observable.fromPromise instead of using just a Observable? :) Catch and throw the error and assign the error response to a variable that you show in template.

Comment: The "save()" methode of the entity returns a promise, therefore I use this way.

Comment: According to Wakanda's [Validate event descript](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datastore/Using-Datastore-Class-Events/Refusing-an-event.300-948259.en.html). The validation error can be caught when you call save() in a try catch. Like @ AJT_82 said, you can also catch and throw the error to a variable assigned to the error response.

Comment: @U.Friedrich I'm from the Wakanda team. If I understood well, in the client side you receive a generic error 500 Internal server error, instead of 'The value is too long'. We are trying to reproduce the issue. If it is reproducible I'll create an issue at: https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to retrieve `validate` error though Angular.

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. I've always seen the default message and then I didn't go deeper into whether the error message from the server is included below.